# Is it a good idea to use Django for an IoT project?

Tags: python, django, iot

I'm thinking to use Django in IoT(Internet of Things) project. Do you thing this is a good idea ? I'm expecting some arguments please.

PS : The project is an industrial project that contain thousands (or more) of devices. And I want to use Django in the server side.

Comment: Have you looked at Ruby on Rails? I've worked in both frameworks and prefer Rails, but both work.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question; can you give more specifics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the framework that fits your needs for your project. 1000 devices is not that much. when django fits your needs so why not?

https://www.djangoproject.com/start/overview/
scroll down. there you see project realized with django.

instagram, pinterest etc.